Load data from a function in a controller with API | SPA Laravel 8
I' am developing a project in Laravel with Vue. I want to implement a filter in a form that allows users to select an item from a table.
The Proyect
I want to put all the values from the ‘filtro’ array into a variable, as shown in the ‘GetFiltro’ function.
Here is my code:

The array:
  filtro: {
          id: '',
          id_solicitud: '',
          id_status: '',
          id_input: '',
          id_output: '',
          id_fechas: ''
      }


The function in the controller:
  async filtroBuscar() {
      console.log('ID del filtro:', this.filtro);  
      await axios.get('/api/getfiltro/' + this.filtro).then(response => {
          this.Item = response.data;
          console.log(this.Item);
          this.getpagina(1);
      }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.Item = []
      })
  }


The function in the controller:
  public function GetFiltro(Request $filtro) {

  $item = rpaSoporteItem::with('relacionSolicitud.relacionProceso.relacionCola','relacionStatus','relacionSubstatus',  'relacionSolicitud.relacionProceso.relaciontipoProceso')->where('id_solicitud','=',$filtro->id_solicitud)>orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

  return response()->json($item);}



Through an API, where I have the get with the function (the image shows it with the ‘id_solicitud’ parameter).”

The API:
  Route::get('getfiltro/{id_solicitud}', 'App\Http\Controllers\ItemController@GetFiltro');



Everything it's working but only with one parameter of de array. I want to know how I can get every single one of them. Because I'm making a filter for the table and it has more than 1 option as you can se in the first picture.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors, images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

What is the question? What did you try and what did not work?

Everything it's working but only with one parameter of de array. I want to know how I can get every single one of them. Because I'm making a filter for the table and it has more than 1 option as you can se in the first picture. Let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

I've fixed the post now @aynber
